# Using two databases during login

Tags: php, mysql, include

I tried implementing a code where I want only those users to register whose email I have stored in one database so that the people of only that particular place can register into the database. So I wanted that during the registeration to the website when user enter the email my scripts checks one database to see if that user can register there and then if yes, check the second database to see if the user has already registered or not then. If not then only register the user.

Comment: Everyone is using separate files to store your classes or plain functions. If it would decrease the performance by a lot, then we all would be still using BASIC style 1 page scripts.

Answer (score 6):

PHP is serverside, so your includes dont have anything to do with the browser cache. Your client connects to your sever, PHP does its processing and then returns the result.

An include just finds the file on the servers disk and executes it. If anything it will be a little slower, however its very unlikely this is a large performance bottleneck. You definitely want to keep your files nice and short, and use includes logically.

If you are optimising its important to identify what is slowing you down first.